# What is the hostname for a Google Cloud PostgreSQL instance?

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database on Google Cloud using SQLAlchemy. Making a connection to the database requires specifying a database URL of the form:  `dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database`

I know what the `dialect + driver` is (postgresql), I know my username and password, and I know the database name. But I don't know how to find the host and port on the Google Cloud console. I've tried using the instance connection name, but that doesn't seem to work. Anyone know where I can find this info on Google Cloud?

Answer (score 8):

- **Hostname**: Please use instance's IP address. There is "IPv4 address" field on the instance overview page in the Cloud Console, e.g. [https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances/[Instance Name]/overview](https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances/[Instance%20Name]/overview)
- **Port**: we use default PostgreSQL port, 5432. I think it is possible to just omit it from the connection string.

Please also see ["Connecting psql Client Using IP Addresses"](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip) page in our docs.

Answer (score 3):

Hostname is the Public IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I want to assume you're making use of the Postgres instance private IP address. That can be gotten from Cloud SQL instances [dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances?authuser=1&project=parentyn-stg).